# Discord py Number guess command

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, bots

So, I have a number guess bot that I need some help adding on to.

How it works is that I have the command

!FinalBalance = !finalbalance (number), and based on whatever number is given it will go through and sort through all the guess entries and find the top 5 people who were closest to the final balance number.

[image: Bot in use.]

Everything works great, but I want to update the !finalbalance command to work like
!finalbalance (amount of winners) (random number) instead of !finalbalance (random number)

You're able to choose the amount of winners / closest guessers instead of it being 5 by default.

Example: !finalbalance 3 4300 .. will send the 3 closest guesses to the random number.

output:
Top 3 Closest Guesses
Final Amount: 4300
1st place: BlahBlah
2nd place: BlahBlahBlah
3rd place: BlahBlahBlah

I would also like for the title to change based on the amount of winners I choose in the command. So !finalbalance 3 (random number), will make the title Top 3 Closest Guesses, and if I did !finalbalance 6 (random number), it would make the title Top 6 Closest Guesses.

Here is the code for the !finalbalance command now.

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator = True)
async def finalbalance(ctx, amount: float = None):
    global winner_decided
    global user_guesses
    global game_started

    if not game_started:
        if winner_decided:
            await ctx.send("Guessing has not started yet.")
            return

    if amount == None:
        await ctx.send("Please specify an amount to decided the winners.")
        return

    if len(user_guesses) == 0:
        await ctx.send("No user has guessed anything.")
        winner_decided = True
        user_guesses = {}
        return

    winners_embed = discord.Embed(title = "Top 5 closest guesses", description = f"Final amount: {amount}\n")
    
    ordinal = lambda n: "%d%s" % (n,"tsnrhtdd"[(n//10%10!=1)*(n%10<4)*n%10::4])
    
    dict_len = len(list(user_guesses.values()))

    for i in range(dict_len if (dict_len <= 5) else 5):
        winner = find_nearest(user_guesses, float(amount))
        del user_guesses[winner[0]]
        winners_embed.add_field(name = f"With ${float(winner[1])} as a guess and ${abs(float(amount) - winner[1])} difference:", value = f"{ordinal(i+1)} place: {winner[0]}", inline = False)

    winners_embed.set_footer(text = f"{dict_len} participants")

    await ctx.send(embed = winners_embed)

    winner_decided = True
    user_guesses = {}
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated :)!

Also if needed, here is my pastebin link to the full source code.
https://pastebin.com/Ay88n6wA

Answer (score 1):

Simply add `guessers` to `finalbalance()` like this:

```
async def finalbalance(ctx, amount: float, guessers: int = 5)
```

Then replace the instances of `5` with `guessers`.

```
for i in range(dict_len if (dict_len <= guessers) else 5):
```

and

```
winners_embed = discord.Embed(title = f"Top {guessers} closest guesses", description = f"Final amount: {amount}\n")
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This works perfectly :)! I have one more question as well, so when people make their guesses. Lets say for example User 1 says !guess 500 and User 2 says !guess 500 And the random number is 500 and they both get it right and win. But whoever did !guess 500 first gets the first place spot, would there be a way to put both users in the first place spot since they both guessed the same correct number? I have been messing around with it and can't get it to function properly.